# Integration by parts, gardient & laplacian

Tags: vector-analysis

I saw the following statement:

If D is a  geometric manifold without boundary in $R^{d}$, then

$ \int_{D} \nabla (f) . \nabla(g) \mathrm{d}x= - \int_{D} f . \Delta(g) \mathrm{d}x$

for $f, g \in H(D) $.

Obviously an integration by parts is going on in the integral, but I couldn't quite grasp it. Can someone explain please :)

Thanx in advance.

Comment: what is $\nabla \cdot \left(f\nabla g\right)$?

Comment: I suppose it's $ \nabla (f) . \nabla(g) + f. \Delta(g)$ .

Answer (score 10):

This is more fundamental than integration by parts - in fact, the strategy is to think about how you prove that integration by parts works.  In the one variable case, integration by parts is obtained by integrating the product rule:

$$\frac{d}{dx}(f \cdot g) = \frac{df}{dx} \cdot g + f \cdot \frac{dg}{dx}$$

and using the fundamental theorem of calculus to simplify the left-hand side.  Your formula is proved the same way: start with some version of the product rule, integrate it, and uses Stokes' theorem (the $d$-dimensional counterpart of the fundamental theorem of calculus) to simplify.  The version of the product rule that we need is:

$$\text{div}(f \nabla g) = \nabla f \cdot \nabla g + f \Delta g$$

Now just integrate everything over $D$.  The integral of $\text{div}(f \nabla g)$ over $D$ is equal to the integral of $f \nabla g$ over the boundary of $D$ by Stokes' theorem, so this integral is $0$ since $D$ has no boundary.

Comment: So can we say that the integration by parts formula is a special case of this formula? Because to me it seems NOT.